# How to update only MAX column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the MAX value's status column with static values in SQL Server:

Script to generate sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
seq INT,
TrnId NVARCHAR(MAX),
Status NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'A1','A')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2,'A1','A')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3,'A1','A')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (4,'A1','P')


INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'B1','A')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2,'B1','A')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3,'B1','A')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (4,'B1','P')


CREATE TABLE #temp
(
TrnId NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('A1')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('B1')
```

I have TrnId In `#temp` table and I want to update only the `MAX` values column for both `TrnId` as `A1` and `B1` with `status = 'A'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example without a CTE:

```
UPDATE A SET A.Status = 'A'
FROM #temp T
INNER JOIN (SELECT TrnId, MAX(seq) as MaxSeq FROM A GROUP BY TrnId) M ON M.TrnId = T.TrnId
INNER JOIN A ON A.TrnId = T.TrnId AND A.seq = M.MaxSeq
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trnid order by status desc) as seqnum
      from a
     )
update toupdate
    set status = 'A'
    from toupdate join
         #temp t
         on toupdate.trnid = t.trnid
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Expected an answer from you!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale. . . It actually has missing `where` clause did you notice ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma yes exactly, that why its showing an 8 rows affected